How do I remove a specific character from a text where it is the first character in the line, using Notepad++?
I have a list of numbers that will start with 1 and +1 so I need to remove the number 1 and +1 from all lines that start with these specific characters. Example:
19178741551
+19178741551
19178741551
9178741551

I need it to be:
9178741551
9178741551
9178741551
9178741551


Use any text editor with regex support, like Notepad++

Search for: ^\+?1
Search mode: Regular expression
Replace with: Empty string

Explanation:

^: Start of line
\+?: Optional literal plus sign
1: the character 1

Or you can do it in PowerShell which also supports regex
$ Get-Content input.txt | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '^\+?1', '' } | `
    Set-Content output.txt
# Or the shortened version:
$ gc input.txt |% { $_ -replace '^\+?1', '' } > output.txt

It'll read the text in input.txt and print the output to output.txt

Why this has been downvoted?

Here is how it might be done in Notepad++, Kate or other text editor using extended search and replace, without harder-to-understand Regular Expressions (regex)
In Windows, end-of line (EOL) is indicated with \r\n [Chr(13) + Chr(10), CR + LF]. so there are two things that might precede those numbers: \r\n, or  , i.e., a space [Chr(32)]. [In older Mac, IBM, Unix and Linux, there are different EOL conventions, so search for EOL would be different.]

First search for \r\n+, and replace with \r\n.
Then search for  +, and replace with  .

Now do the same for initial 1.

First search for \r\n1, and replace with \r\n.
Then search for  1, and replace with  .

With those four steps, thousands of initial +1 and 1 numbers would be changed in seconds.
A screenshot from Notepad++ is below.

Caveat:
The very first line of a document is not preceded by EOL, so you'll need to check and edit that one line manually, if it begins with 1 or +1. Sorry about that extra work ;-)

That's quite cumbersome, and won't work for the first line because the character 1 there isn't prefixed by \r\n. In fact you only need to match \n1 which will work for both CRLF and LF files, no need to check for \r
